# ionic keyboard go button to next button

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Reference:[Change go button to next button in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U7Jq.jpg)

I am developing an application with sign up page using Ionic framework.

Is there any option to replace go button with next button? I want to move cursor from one field to another using next button in the keyboard.

Comment: i see cancel button Sara

Comment: Cancel button was added in the ion footer to cancel sign up page.  Is there any option to change Go button with next button to move cursor  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following reference to achieve your requirement in ionic.Below code is for cordova

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.enterAsTab = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            'allowSubmit': false
        }, options);
        this.find('input, select, textarea, button').live("keypress", {localSettings: settings}, function(event) {
            if (settings.allowSubmit) {
                var type = $(this).attr("type");
                if (type == "submit") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input:visible:not(disabled):not([readonly])");
                var idx = inputs.index(this);
                if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
                    idx = -1;
                } else {
                    inputs[idx + 1].focus(); // handles submit buttons
                }
                try {
                    inputs[idx + 1].select();
                }
                catch (err) {
                    // handle objects not offering select
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

For adding next button , you can refer following link:
[How to add Next button in Ionic soft keyboard plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174953/how-to-add-next-button-in-ionic-soft-keyboard-plugin?rq=1)